Webapp > Youtube > Sign in to confirm that you're not a bot error
I am integrating youtube player using the `react-player ' package. It works well on chrome but on safari and other browsers it's asking to signin without any link/option to signin.
Youtube is signed in in other tab but getting the same error.
How to solve this error? it it global for all players(packages) or any work around?
I tried logging in to youtube on there official site, no luck error screenshot here

I use `react-player' to play YouTube videos (next.js 14+).
I get an identical issue: it works in Chrome but not Safari or Firefox.
The issue was gone when I swapped to another VPN server and got a new IP.

I'm having similar issue and it happens only with Safari, both Firefox and Chrome do not exhibit this behavior. This means, there must be something related to how Safari accesses the YouTube. I think this behavior can be eliminated by unchecking Safari -> Settings -> Privacy -> Hide IP address from trackers.

Solution for me was to disable the VPN
